# I want to share a JPA annotated entity model over a several JEE6 WEB projects

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I want to share an entity model, annotated with JPA, over a several JEE6 WEB projects. The entities are annotated like this:

```
@Entity
public class Contract implements Serializable {
```

I created a maven project with only annotated entity classes, the entity project.

In the client JEE6 WEB project I created a dependency on this entity project. The JEE6 project is able to compile, but when executing on a Glassfish application server there is a runtime error. The class is not recognized as a Entity class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: nl.marcenschede.modules.Contract[ id=null ] is not a known entity type.
```

What to do for an imported class to be recognized as an entity project?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://slackspace.de/articles/jpa-persistence-modular-maven-application/) for working example of how to do this.

Comment: @RalfHoppen Hehe, I feel that I need to credit avatar author: http://aangry.deviantart.com/art/BMO-327660345 . Spread the awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to package the persistence unit classes inside a jar with a `META-INF` folder containing the `persistence.xml` file listing all entities classes.

The resulting jar must be then included in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web-apps war files.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrj